# What is the syntax to bring up the man page for a puppet subcommand in 2.6?

Tags: puppet

I tried `$ puppet help master` but got an error.  Apparently this syntax only works in version 3.2

Comment: have you already tried `apropos puppet`?

Comment: Post the error you got. Also, works for me in `2.7.18`, which, by the way is old enough as there is no docs (or I couldn't find it) for puppet < 2.7 in [puppetlabs.com](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/index.html)